reading files from directory in Android
Recently I had to make an application that should read files from the device, such as photos, videos, music, etc. When I wanted to open a folder with downloads, images, music or another folder, my program could not read them. The thing is that I can not access any files outside of my application at all, I do not get any errors, for example, if I want to open the Downloads folder and then get a list of files that are in it, using the list() method, it returns null
Please help me solve this problem.
MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //private TextView  t;
    private Button bt;
    private File File;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;

        });

        bt = findViewById(R.id.button);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                val downloadFolder = requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS
                System.out.println("btn_click!");
//                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

//                System.out.println(path);
//                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
//                }

                File f = new File("sdcard");
                String[] s = f.list();
                File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file

                File file = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)));
                String[] text = file.list();
//Read text from file

                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(text));
            }
//                for(int i=0;i < f.length;i++){
//                    System.out.println(s[i]);
//                }

        });
    }

}

manifect.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!--    <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"-->
<!--        tools:ignore="ReservedSystemPermission" />-->



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28"
       />

    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.New_proj"

        android:protectionLevel="normal"

        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


"if I want to open the Downloads folder and then get a list of files that are in it, using the list() method, it returns null" -- you have no rights to files in Downloads or Documents,  unless your current app installation created those files. "should read files from the device, such as photos, videos, music, etc." -- for photos, videos, and music, use MediaStore. For everything else, use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT / ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument).

"READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" is deprecated (and is not granted) when targeting Android 13+. If you need to write to shared storage, use the MediaStore"
As of Android 13, if you need to query or interact with MediaStore or media files on the shared storage, you should be using instead one or more new storage permissions:


android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES
android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO
android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO


You can use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE but if you can't justify the requirement for such broad access to all files, google play will reject your app. Instead, use the above mentioned permissions to access Images, Video and Audio. But remember, you won't have access to other files
If you need to continuously interact with your own files without user action, you can use app specific external storage access (Android/data/your-package-name)
Or if you want access to all files but user can choose the files on their own, you can use Android's file picker and you won't need additional permissions

Android applications are typically sandboxed, meaning that any app only has access to its own data unless permissions are specifically requested by the app and granted by the user.
In your manifest, you already have the line:
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

That line demonstrates how your app can access the SD card on a device. View the list of permissions to see which ones you want to request and add a uses-permission as necessary in your manifest.xml.

As an additional aspect to the answer: The java.io.File API is stupid which is why it was replaced 15 years ago. It's stupid in that it just deals with errors by returning 0/null/false, so, you have no idea what's wrong. However, I'm not sure the API that replaced it that is not stupid in that sense (i.e. it gives you proper errors that explain what is wrong) is available on android. If it is; it's java.nio.file.*.

"That line demonstrates how your app can access the SD card on a device" -- READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not used on modern versions of Android. Even before then, it only infrequently dealt with an SD card.
